# Format dependent rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, single-page-application, singlepage

How to realize the following routing in rails:

- if the request is requiring `html`, than route to a specific action, let's say application#index
- in case of a `json` format request, route to the resources just normally to action which produce the requested `json`

Obviously that's a use case for a single page application, where rails is mostly used only for serving `json`s. Most of the pages are just very simple layouts with some values bootstrapped.

Thanks for hints.

Answer (score 1):

The way this problem is solved in Rails can be handled in the controller in a single action. In the routes file you would just declare the resource:

```
resources :posts
```

And the controller would look like this:

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html  # index.html.erb
    format.json  { render :json => @posts }
  end
end
```

As you can see, the type of the response depends on the type requested.

However, if you really do want to route according to type I guess you could try something like this:

```
match 'posts/:id.:format' => 'posts#html_respond', :constraints => {:format => "html"}
match 'posts/:id.:format' => 'posts#json_respond', :constraints => {:format => "json"}
```